# How to parse string to map in java

Tags: java, string-parsing

How to write parser for below string in java

`"SiteId:BLR232#Latitude:12.918444#Longitude:77.5940136#NetworkType:4g#Type:NONE#Type of Complaint:Call Drop#Sample Number:7022979575#Problem Description:agshjs vshsijsb#"`

so that result output will be in hashmap java

```
Key = SiteId, Value = BLR232
Key = Type, Value = NONE
Key = Problem Description, Value = agshjs vshsijsb
Key = Sample Number, Value = 7022979575
Key = NetworkType, Value = 4g
Key = Latitude, Value = 12.918444
Key = Type of Complaint, Value = Call Drop
Key = Longitude, Value = 77.5940136
```

I had tried using `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):(\\w+)");` but not working exactly what i need.

Comment: i had tried using Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+):(\\w+)"); but not working exactly what i need

Comment: I think [`([^#:]+):([^#]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kL9iY8/2) should be enough. Or split with `#`  and then split each chunk with `:`.

Comment: or `([^:]+):([^#]+)#`

Comment: also, simple split probably will be faster

Comment: There is no reason for marking the post as off-topic: it has a clear description, expected behavior, and OP provided the efforts (in the comments first though, moved to the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(\w+):(\w+)` only matches single words before `:` and after it. You have `#` as a record delimiter and `:` as a key-value delimiter, so you cannot rely on just `\w` class.

Note that you can solve the problem with just splitting the string with `#` into key-value pairs and then split each key-value pair with `:`:

```
String str = "SiteId:BLR232#Latitude:12.918444#Longitude:77.5940136#NetworkType:4g#Type:NONE#Type of Complaint:Call Drop#Sample Number:7022979575#Problem Description:agshjs vshsijsb#";
String[] kvps = str.split("#");
Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(String kvp : kvps) {
    String[] parts = kvp.split(":");
    res.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
    System.out.println(parts[0] + " - " + parts[1]); // just demo
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/G94adq)

If you need a regex by all means, you can use the following pattern with `Matcher#find()`:

```
([^#:]+):([^#]+)
```

Explanation:

- `([^#:]+)` - 1+ characters other than `#` and `:` (thus, we stay inside the key-value pair and match the key)
- `:` - a literal colon
- `([^#]+)` - 1+ characters other than `#` (thus, we match the value up to the `#`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kL9iY8/2)